# Ошибка при использовании PHP функции compact()

Tags: php, массивы, symfony

В Symfony 6.1 на PHP 8.1 генерирую такой массив в переменную $user:

```
array:2 [▼
  "us" => array:5 [▼
    "id" => "8b8170f4-6d73-42bb-b02b-34ae3f175857"
    "email" => null
    "date" => "2022-07-27 15:48:50"
    "role" => "ROLE_USER"
    "status" => "active"
  ]
  "networks" => array:1 [▼
    0 => array:2 [▼
      "network" => "github"
      "identity" => "104368371"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Далее пытаюсь отправить её в Twig:

```
return $this->render("app/profile/show.html.twig", compact($user));
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
Warning: compact(): Undefined variable $8b8170f4-6d73-42bb-b02b-34ae3f175857
```

Почему из значения ключа "id" он пытается сделать переменную, добавляя впереди $?
Мне всего-то нужен аналог

```
return $this->render("app/profile/show.html.twig", ['user' => $user]);
```

Comment: В [руководство](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.compact.php#refsect1-function.compact-parameters) вот прям написано "Массив может содержать вложенные массивы названий переменных; функция `compact()` обрабатывает их рекурсивно. ". То есть `8b8170f4-6d73-42bb-b02b-34ae3f175857` и `ROLE_USER` и все остальные значения - это __названия переменных__, которых у тебя естественно нет.

Comment: А писать в итоге надо `compact('user')`

Comment: compact работает здорово медленнее обычного массива, рекомендую использовать массив `return $this->render("app/profile/show.html.twig", ['user' => $user]);`